# Android RecyclerView Popop Activity - 5 second popup time

Tags: android, kotlin

So I've been working on a RecyclerView recently that's in a popup, and it takes a few seconds to popup with around 100 items. I want to make this faster, so any improvements on my code is appreciated :)

layout/activity_supervisor_order_popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".layoutfiles.SupervisorView.OrderPopup">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/materialsTitle"
                android:textSize="70dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
        />

        <!--<include layout="@layout/card_supervisor_order_item"-->
                 <!--android:layout_below="@+id/materialsTitle"-->
                 <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                 <!--android:layout_height="0dp"-->
                 <!--android:layout_weight="0.1"-->
                 <!--android:id="@+id/firstRow"/>-->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/popupRecycler"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="0dp"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_weight="0.1"
        >

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/orderSelectedButton"
                    android:text="Order Selected"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
            />

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/orderAllButton"
                    android:text="Order All"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

            />

            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                    android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

card_supervisor_order_item.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:id="@+id/workOrderCardView"
                                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                   app:cardBackgroundColor="#FCFCFC"
                                   app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                                   app:cardElevation="3dp"
                                   app:contentPadding="4dp"
                                   android:gravity="center"
                                   tools:context=".layoutfiles.SupervisorView.OrderPopup"

>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:gravity="center"
    >
        <TableRow
        >

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/addRemove"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/item_order_unchecked"
            />
            <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@+id/materialName"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/materialQty"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

OrderPopup.kt

````
package com.rkalim.digifloor.layoutfiles.SupervisorView

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.*
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.rkalim.digifloor.R
import com.rkalim.digifloor.models.RequiredItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recycler_supervisor_order.*

class OrderPopup : Activity() {
    lateinit var adapter: RequiredItemAdapter
    lateinit var titleFromIntent: String
    var dataListSend: MutableList<RequiredItem> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

        var extras = intent.extras

        if (extras != null) {
            titleFromIntent = extras.getString("title")
            Log.d("PutExtra", titleFromIntent)
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_supervisor_order_popup)
        getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        var sendAllButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.orderAllButton)
        var sendSelectedButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.orderSelectedButton)
        var cancel = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancelButton)

        sendAllButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { sendAll() })
        sendSelectedButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { sendSelected() })
        cancel.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { cancel() })

        popupRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        addData()
        adapter = RequiredItemAdapter(this, dataListSend)
        popupRecycler.adapter = adapter
    }

    fun sendAll() {
        send(ArrayList(dataListSend))
        this.finish()
    }

    fun sendSelected() {
        var selectedItems = adapter.selected
        send(selectedItems)
        this.finish()
    }

    fun cancel() {
        this.finish()
    }

    fun send(list: ArrayList<RequiredItem>) {
        if (list.size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this@OrderPopup, "Please select at least one item.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }

        var notifContent = StringBuilder()
        notifContent.append(titleFromIntent + " order received from CNC")
        var i = 1

        notifContent.append("\n")
        for (item in list) {
            notifContent.append(i.toString() + ") " + item.qty + " quantity of " + item.item)
            notifContent.append("\n")
            i++
        }
        var notifTitle = "New Order"

        var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID)
        builder.setContentTitle(notifTitle)
        builder.setContentText("Order for " + dataListSend.size.toString() + titleFromIntent)
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp)
        builder.setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notifContent))
        var mNotifManager = (this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
        if (mNotifManager is NotificationManager) {
            mNotifManager.notify(999, builder.build())
        }
    }

    fun addData() {
        //This is actually replaced with an API Call to get the data. However, this isn't the performance issue!
        var items = arrayListOf<String>("Paint A","Paint B","Paint C", "Tape", "Socks", "Pants")
        for (i in 1..100) {
            var item = RequiredItem(items.get((0..5).shuffled().first()), (1..10000).shuffled().first().toString())
            dataListSend.add(item)
        }
    }

    class RequiredItemAdapter(internal var context: Context, internal var itemList: List<RequiredItem>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RequiredItemAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {
        private var imgList: List<RequiredItem> = itemList;
        //        var selected: MutableList<RequiredItem> = ArrayList()
        var selected = ArrayList<RequiredItem>()

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.materialName.setText(imgList.get(position).item)
            holder.materialQty.setText(imgList.get(position).qty)
            var clicked = false

            holder.toggle.setOnClickListener {
                if (clicked) {
                    selected.remove(imgList.get(position))
                    clicked = false
                    holder.toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_order_unchecked)
                    Log.d("LIST", selected.toString())

                } else {
                    selected.add(imgList.get(position))
                    clicked = true
                    holder.toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.order_item_checked)
                    Log.d("LIST", selected.toString())
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_supervisor_order_item, parent, false)
            return CustomViewHolder(
                cellForRow
            )
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return imgList.size
        }

        class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            var materialName: TextView
            var materialQty: TextView
            var toggle: ImageView

            init {
                materialName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.materialName)
                materialQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.materialQty)
                toggle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addRemove)
            }
        }
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score -1):

First sight of layout/activity_supervisor_order_popup.xml: no need having the first LinearLayout at least.

Comment: Welcome to code review! Can you explain what that element isn’t needed?

Comment: The first LinearLayout wraps textView (with id materialsTitle) and the recyclerView. It can be done by using constraintLayout relative positioning